# Does a continuous and surjective function $f: ]0,1[ \rightarrow [0,1]$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that $f^{-1}(Imf)=f^{-1}(f(\ ]0,1[\ ))=\ ]0,1[$ but since $f$ is surjective $Im(f) = [0,1]$ so:
$$f^{-1}([0,1])=\ ]0,1[$$
and that is not possible since the function is continuous. Anyway my text affirms that such a function exists but i can't figure out where is the mistake in my argument. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example of such a continuous, surjective function would be $f(x)=\sin^2(2\pi x)$. This is clearly continuous, and we have, e.g., $f(\frac14)=1$, $f(\frac12)=0$.

Why doesn't this fall afoul of the theorem telling us that the inverse image of a closed set, under a continuous function, is closed? Recall that, when we define a function on the domain $]0,1[$, we are taking $]0,1[$ as our entire space, and it is therefore closed *in itself*. If we were working in $\Bbb R$, then the inverse image of $[0,1]$ would be more than just the open interval - it would be all of $\Bbb R$, which is again, closed in itself.

Comment: I clearly understand my mistake. Anyway now i'm not able to demonstrate why it doesn't exist a continuous and surjective function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow ]0,1[$ because i had used the same, erroneous, argument. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact. The closed interval is compact, but the open interval is not, not even in itself.